# How can I send a function through http request in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fetch

How can I send a function through http request in reactjs?

```
    const callback = (action) => {
            store.dispatch(action);
        };

    const data = {
        params: {validatedUser : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))},
        callback
    }
```

how can pass this data object to nodejs server?

Answer (score 0):

You can send only string through HTTP request. Try:

```
const data = {
        params: {validatedUser : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))},
        JSON.stringify(callback)
    }
```

Then parse it on your backend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I tried it. When callback is stringify then it is undefined on backend.